# Creating a web Service from wsdl using apache axis

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

i am new bee to web service world. i am given a wsdl file and asked to write a web service corresponding to this wsdl file. Is it possible to generate web service from wsdl file .

I have generated client using wsdl file using apche axis wsdl2java but how will write server side code from wsdl.

please help me out to generate web service from wsdl file using apche axis .

Comment: from [the documentation](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html) -ss                      Generate server side code (i.e. skeletons) (Default: off).

Comment: will it generate classes required for web service??

Comment: What does `classes required for web service` means?

Comment: i knew that apache wsdl2java is used to create client code to invoke service on the server. i wanted to know will it generate classes on the server side that will be exposed through wsdl

Comment: Yes that is what wsdl2java -ss ... does

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java to generate java stub or skeleton using your WSDL file